# Error:535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. In nodemailer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, email, nodemailer

So I created mern stack e-commerce application, using nodejs as a server.I tried to send confirmation email to new users, using nodemailer and gmail as the host.I tried to enable 2-step verification and generate a password as I should, but still I don't get any emails and also recieves the error written in the title. Can anyone help?

**Class I created containing the function that sending the emails:**

```
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
export const sendEmail=async(subject,message,send_to,send_from,reply_to)=>{
    var transporter=nodemailer.createTransport({
      service:process.env.EMAIL_SERVICE,
      auth:{
        user:process.env.EMAIL_USER,
        pass:process.env.EMAIL_PASS
      },
      tls:{
      rejectUnauthorized:false,
      }
    });
    const options={
      from:send_from,
      to:send_to,
      replyTo:reply_to,
      subject,
      html:message,

    }
    transporter.sendMail(options,function(err,info){
      if(err){
        console.log(err)
      }
      else{
        console.log(info) 
       }
    })
    
    }
    export default sendEmail;
```

**The registration route:**

```
export const register=catchAsync(async(req,res,next)=>{
  const{fullName,email,password,confirmPassword,type,Wishlist}=req.body;
  if(!fullName||!email||!password||!confirmPassword||!type){
    return next(new ErrorHandling("One or more of the fields is empty",400));
  }
  if(password!=confirmPassword){
    return next(new ErrorHandling("Password fields does not equal",400));
  }
  if(!validateEmail(email)){
    return next(new ErrorHandling("The email you entered is illegal",400));
  }
  if(await User.findOne({email})){
    return next(new ErrorHandling("Email already exists",400));
  }
  try{
  await sendEmail('Consumer account confirmation',`<h3>Welcome to Base herbal cosmetics</h3><p>Thank you for your registration</p><button>press here to join</button>`,process.env.EMAIL_USER,email,email)
  }catch(err){
    return next(new ErrorHandling(err.message,err.statusCode));
  }
 const newUser=await User.create({
    fullName,
    email,
    password,
    confirmPassword,
    type,
    Wishlist
 })  

 res.status(201).json({
    status:"success",
    data:{
        newUser
    }
})

});
```

It is worth to mention that users do added to my database and everything but the emails works fine.

Comment: The error (inconveniently stuffed into the title) seems to hint that your credentials are invalid. The rest of the code is irrelevant if that is the case. Test that your credentials are correct, and that the environment variables you're using are correctly populated. Right now this code does not error out if those are `undefined`.

Comment: For what it's worth, you have a very unusual coding style with a lot of strange "cramping". Normally an assignment is `x = y` not `x=y`, and properties are generally listed as `x: y` not `x:y` as a little space helps readability considerably. Likewise, `if (...)` helps differentiate from a function call.

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment.Sadly the credientials do correct,I set service as gmail, user as my email and pass as the password recieved, as far as credentials everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

From your Google account settings, click on Security tab, go to 2-step verification and enable it (it's ok since it is enabled already).
Now under 2-step verification, scroll down to App Passwords, generate a unique password, and use it in your code instead of the traditional password you use when logging into your email.

The reason this is so is due to Google security. When logging in traditionally, there is another step of verification after inputting password; but since NodeMailer uses only one password stage, that's why Google provided that option for those who may want to access their account *programmically*.